# ComboBox Search Key Press Interval

Tags: linux, qt, keyboard, debian, x11

I have a Qt user interface running under X11 on Debian Linux. I have a dropdown list (QComboBox) with numbers. If the combo box is active, and I press the keys quickly one after another, I can search for and go directly to the list item.

Example: I have a list from 1...521 in the ComboBox. If I press the keys [3][4][2] quickly, then then the 342 is selected in the combobox. This feature is common to many applications (web browsers, etc).

How can I change the time allowed between the key presses? I need to allow the users to press the buttons slowly while still maintaining the search state.

Comment: It can be set in VIM: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744631/way-to-delay-the-timeout-of-key-sequences-in-vim)

Comment: yes, I see but I need to set it global (Linux or Qt)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This feature is implemented in Qt, not in the X server. The searching is done via `QAbstractItemView::keyboardSearch` on the internal list view. The time allowed between the key presses is controlled by the `QApplication::keyboardInputInterval` property.

For example, to change it to 1 second (1000 ms):

```
qApp.setKeyboardInputInterval(1000);
```

As crazy as it might sound, every application development framework out there reimplements this functionality :(