# Is it possible to always overwrite a specific built-in command with a particular mapped command?

Tags: vim

I have the following mapping in my `.vimrc`.

```
" Scroll arbitrary
function ScrollToPercent(percent)
    let movelines=winheight(0)*a:percent/100

    if has("float") && type(movelines)==type(0.0)
        let movelines=float2nr(movelines)
    endif

    let oldso=&so
    execute ":set so=" . movelines
    execute "normal! zt"
    execute ":set so=" . oldso
endfunction

nnoremap zz :call ScrollToPercent(25)<CR>
```

This mapping causes the command `zz` to move the line under the current cursor to `25%` of the way down from the top of the screen, instead of the usual behavior of moving it `50%` of the way down.

I have observed that, if I type the second `z` with slightly greater delay after the first `z`, my mapping is ignored and the default behavior of `zz` kicks in. In particular, the line under my cursor will move to `50%` of the way down instead of `25%` of the way down.

Based on the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744631/way-to-delay-the-timeout-of-key-sequences-in-vim), I could `set timeoutlen` to some high value, but I do not want to do this because it will mess up other mappings which should **not** be kicked off if a small delay separates the keys.

Is it possible to make my mapping for `zz` always override the default `zz`, without changing some global option that will affect other mappings?

Answer (score 1):

You could map a single `z` to a no-op. Then if you quickly type `zz` then your cursor will jump, if you wait too long nothing at all will happen.

I.e. use this pair of mappings:

```
nnoremap zz :call ScrollToPercent(25)<CR>
nnoremap z  <NOP>
```