# How to map a key in vim dependent of how often it is pressed?

Tags: vim

I've mapped the key 0 so that the cursor jumps to the first non-blank character in line with following line:

```
map 0 ^
```

Now i want that the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line by pushing 0 twice.

How can I do this?

Comment: You mean like `map 00 ^` ?

Comment: more like `map 0 ^` and `map 00 $`.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: sorry that was wrong. i actually mean like `map 0 ^` and `map 00 0`, do you know what i mean?

Comment: Yes, but that still works. It's called a recursive map. [More information](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Mapping_keys_in_Vim_-_Tutorial_%28Part_1%29#Nested_.28recursive.29_maps)

Comment: You may also like [this solution](http://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5695/1800) - toggles `0` and `^` functionality when `0` is repeatedly pressed. No lag.

Comment: @jervis I suggest you to try read some docs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just put `map 00 ^`
Vim will wait a bit to see if anything else is pressed in such cases.

From the comments following, I got more insights to different ways to solve this. One solution can be found [here (Smart home).](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Smart_home)

The relevant portions of that wiki:

The following lines (in your vimrc) implement smart home for normal, visual, operator pending, and insert modes.

```
noremap <expr> <silent> <Home> col('.') == match(getline('.'),'\S')+1 ? '0' : '^'imap <silent> <Home> <C-O><Home>
```

The first line is an expression mapping for normal, visual, and operator pending modes. The right-hand side of the mapping is an expression that is evaluated each time Home is pressed. The expression gives a string, and the result is as if the characters in the string had been pressed. The expression compares `col('.')` (the cursor column position, where 1 is the first column) and `match(getline('.'),'\S')+1` (the index of the first non-whitespace character in the current line; 1 is added because the index starts at 0). If both sides of `==` are equal, the result is `0` (move to start of line); otherwise it is `^` (move to first nonblank character).

In insert mode, the second line applies and if Home is pressed the result is Ctrl-O followed by Home. In insert mode, pressing Ctrl-O executes what follows as a normal-mode command, so the Home which follows invokes the normal mode mapping.

Comment: That works and is the correct answer. But is it possible to adjust the delay?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9744631/way-to-delay-the-timeout-of-key-sequences-in-vim

Comment: hm, this is not exactly the behaviour i wanted. now i need to push the key twice when i'm at the first non-blank character to get to the beginning of the line. I wanted to push it once then.

Comment: I believe you'be removed `map 0 ^`.  Now 00 moves to first non blank character and 0 moves to beginning of line.

Comment: I'm sorry but it  was not really clear from the question. I'll update my answer.